# Как в jQuery высчитать процент

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Есть фрагмент кода для wp woocommerce:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select').blur( function(){
        if( '' != $('input.variation_id').val() ){
            $('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');
            console.log($('input.variation_id').val());
        } else {
            $('p.price').html($('div.hidden-variable-price').html());
            if($('p.availability'))
                $('p.availability').remove();
            console.log('NULL');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Нужно чтобы результат был `console.log - 10%` Как так сделать? Можете подсказать, а то я в jQuery вообще ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Эээ? Вспомнить школьную математику и определение процента?

Comment: Да ежу понятно нужно `* 0.9` я спрашиваю как код правильно написать на jQuery. Как к этому `$('p.price').html($('div.woocommerce-variation-price > span.price').html()).append('<p class="availability">'+$('div.woocommerce-variation-availability').html()+'</p>');` добавить это `* 0.9`  ????

Comment: Что означает * 0,9? Это вы типа получили свои 10%?

Comment: Да, обычный пример на php 
`$price = 100;
$price_got = $price * 0.9; 
echo $price_got; 
Ответ: 90; `

Как это сделать на jQuery в указанным выше коде?